# SAS Retain values by two or more groups

Tags: sas

I need help with retaining values inside two o more groups. All samples I can find are with only one group.

My groups look like:

Group_A  : A1, A2
Group_B  : B1, B2, B3

My dataset is:

```
data have;
input mydate:ddmmyy10. Group_A $ Group_B $ Val;
format mydate ddmmyy10.;

datalines;
01/04/2022 A1 B1 10
02/04/2022 A1 B1 10
03/04/2022 A1 B1 .
04/04/2022 A1 B1 .
05/04/2022 A1 B1 .
01/04/2022 A1 B2 .
02/04/2022 A1 B2 .
03/04/2022 A1 B2 20
04/04/2022 A1 B2 .
05/04/2022 A1 B2 .
01/04/2022 A1 B3 .
02/04/2022 A1 B3 40
03/04/2022 A1 B3 .
04/04/2022 A1 B3 42
05/04/2022 A1 B3 .
01/04/2022 A2 B1 .
02/04/2022 A2 B1 .
03/04/2022 A2 B1 15
04/04/2022 A2 B1 .
05/04/2022 A2 B1 .
;
run;
```

I want the following results:

```
data want;
input mydate:ddmmyy10. Group_A $ Group_B $ Val;
format mydate ddmmyy10.;

datalines;
01/04/2022 A1 B1 10
02/04/2022 A1 B1 10
03/04/2022 A1 B1 10
04/04/2022 A1 B1 10
05/04/2022 A1 B1 10
01/04/2022 A1 B2 .
02/04/2022 A1 B2 .
03/04/2022 A1 B2 20
04/04/2022 A1 B2 20
05/04/2022 A1 B2 20
01/04/2022 A1 B3 .
02/04/2022 A1 B3 40
03/04/2022 A1 B3 40
04/04/2022 A1 B3 42
05/04/2022 A1 B3 42
01/04/2022 A2 B1 .
02/04/2022 A2 B1 .
03/04/2022 A2 B1 15
04/04/2022 A2 B1 15
05/04/2022 A2 B1 15
;
run;
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want to do a last observation carried forward (LOCF).  You can use the UPDATE statement to help you do that.

Normally the UPDATE statement is used to apply transactions from a TRANSACTION dataset to a BASE dataset.  When a transaction observation has a missing value for a variable that means to not make any change to that variable.

For LOCF application you can use the original dataset as the BASE dataset (in addition to being the TRANSACTION dataset) by using the OBS=0 dataset option.  To not collapse to one observation per by group add an OUTPUT statement.

```
data want;
   update have(obs=0) have;
   by group_a group_b;
   output;
run;
```

Comment: Excellent way to acheive LOCF, I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

A `BY` statement lists variables whose combination defines the group.  There are automatic flag variables `FIRST.variable` and `LAST.variable` that are set to `1` at the start/end of a group and `0` otherwise.

When the statement lists more than one variable you now have access to changes within the tiers of the combination (i.e. hierarchy).  The flags of the lower tiers change more rapidly than those of the higher tiers.

Example:

It appears you are continuing a value in a group (i.e. tier) once it has been observed.  You will need a tracking variable or a judicious use of the `LAG` function.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by group_a group_b;
  retain val_tracker;

  if first.group_b then 
    call missing(val_tracker);

  if not missing(val) 
    then val_tracker = val;  /* new value to track */
    else val = val_tracker;  /* apply tracked value */

  drop val_tracker;
run;
```